# Laravel - Best way to bind class, only if User logged in

Tags: laravel, binding

I need to bind singleton class only if User Logged in... I know that the best place where I should bind my class is the Service Provider and method register(), but at this stage user аuthentication has not started yet.

I solve this problem by binding in Event like this:

```
Event::listen('Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated', function ($authenticated) {
    app()->singleton( MyClass::class, function ($app) use($authenticated) {
        // $authenticated->user or Request::user()
        return new MyClass( Request::user() );
    });
});
```

This code works fine, but I`m not sure that it is good idea. What is the best?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: define best? does it really matter its a single class that you are binding to that you likely will never touch the binding again. in my opinion we tend to care about soo many of those that we waste enough time to develop. push your product and refactor once you came across this 3 times in the future.

Answer (score 1):

How about this in your service provider (AppServiceProvider) for example?

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        app()->singleton(MyClass::class, function ($app) {
            return new MyClass(Auth::user());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already wrote in the question, Auth::check() will be always == false, because at this stage user аuthentication has not started yet.

Comment: In that case I have to agree with Sari Yono's earlier comment.